# Outlook 2010 photos not showing in sent email header

Tags: outlook, pictures

I have been searching around in other posts but the common solution is to turn off "Show users photos when available" I know how to do that and that is not what I need a solution for at the moment.

Currently, when I send an email my photo appears in the email header and other users can see it. However I have had people ask how I activated this feature and I have no idea. My photo is not added in AD I have only added it in outlook. We have compared settings between me and someone who is not working and can't find a difference.

One thing I did notice is I see my picture next to account settings, one of the other users sees his picture everywhere but there and there is no option to add the picture there.

Any advice on how to activate this feature for other users?

Answer (score 1):

Free, great product....done:

http://www.exclaimer.com/outlook-photos/

(by the way, I'm assuming you are the IT admin involved...otherwise this really belongs on superuser.com)

Or see the answer here on Superuser for a "non-admin" way of doing it (ie. manually via the client side): https://superuser.com/questions/500095/how-do-i-add-my-photo-to-my-account-in-outlook-2010

Comment: I am the IT admin, and I will check out the product. However, if mine is working and I know my photo is not in AD it would be great to the know the setting I am missing to get others working without having to add them to AD.

Comment: Sure...I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I came across that article earlier in my searches and we've already done that. I assume at this point I have some sort of registry setting making mine visable in emails sent to others. The person I am setting up see's their picture in Lync, OWA, our Global address book contact card, and if they open a sent email they see it. However when the email is sent to others we do not see the picture. and I have contact photos turned on.

Comment: Exchange 2010 on the back end?  Do they show in the People Pane?  Have you tried this? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/turn-on-or-off-photos-of-message-senders-and-recipients-HA102080340.aspx

Comment: Hosted Office 365 on the backend. Their photos do not show in my people pane, however they do show if I hover over them in the global address book and in lync. On their computer they see their picture in the people pane and when I email them they see mine.

Comment: Ah, sorry!  OK, what about their Office 365 profile?  If they log into the portal does it show a pic for them?  Do you and them see the right pics in the OWA inside the O365 portal?

Comment: Yep their pics show in the Portal and OWA, the only place my picture is showing that theirs isn't is in outlook when you go to file\Info I have a picture next to Account settings, they don't. Everywhere else has the right picture.

Comment: Interesting since hitting the "change" under the pic on `Account Settings` will redirect to the portal to login and change it there (at least on Outlook 2013, don't have a 2010).  I'm at a loss, if you create a new profile for a user (don't bother deleting the existing, just new one in Mail control panel), does it suddenly work?  Sorry, I was assuming too much in my original answer, but would like to help you get to the bottom of it.